# Kubeflow setup returns no resources found

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes, kubeflow

I am following the steps in the getting started guide for [kubeflow](https://github.com/kubeflow/website/blob/master/content/docs/started/getting-started-minikube.md) and i got stuck at verify the setup works.

I managed to get this:-

```
$ kubectl get ns
NAME             STATUS    AGE
default          Active    2m
kube-public      Active    2m
kube-system      Active    2m
kubeflow-admin   Active    14s
```

but when i do

```
$ kubectl -n kubeflow get svc
No resources found.
```

I also got

```
$ kubectl -n kubeflow get pods
No resources found.
```

I repeated these both on my mac and my ubuntu VM, and both returned the same problem. Am i missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you're missing something here and that is to use the correct namespace. Use:

```
$ kubectl -n kubeflow-admin get all
```

Comment: ah... i got it.. I was expecting it to be immediate. so I ran kubectl -n kubeflow-admin get all as you said and I saw that the containers are spinning up. took a couple of minutes before i ran the kubectl -n kubeflow get pods again and see the results. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. I follow [this guide](https://v0-2.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-minikube/). But I cannot get the results of `kubectl -n kubeflow get pods` even after I wait for long time. This is [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73329904/setup-kubeflow-on-minikube-no-resources-found-in-kubeflow-namespace#autocomment129510528).

Answer (score 1):

The process of installing the Kubeflow services involves downloading the container images and therefore it takes time for the services to get up and running.

You can run the command periodically until they are up.