# Setup Kubeflow on minikube: No resources found in kubeflow namespace

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubeflow

When I try to setup kubeflow with minikube on my local desktop(Ubuntu 20.0.4) and run `kubectl create -f bootstrapper.yaml` according to [this official document](https://v0-2.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-minikube/), I got the `AlreadyExists` following error.

> Error from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating
> "bootstrapper.yaml": namespaces "kubeflow-admin" already exists Error
> from server (AlreadyExists): error when creating "bootstrapper.yaml":
> persistentvolumeclaims "kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc" already exists [unable
> to recognize "bootstrapper.yaml": no matches for kind
> "ClusterRoleBinding" in version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
> unable to recognize "bootstrapper.yaml": no matches for kind
> "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta2"]

After deleting namespace and persistent volume and run the same command, then I got this `version` error messages.

> namespace/kubeflow-admin created
> persistentvolumeclaim/kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc created unable to recognize
> "bootstrapper.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterRoleBinding" in
> version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1" unable to recognize
> "bootstrapper.yaml": no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version
> "apps/v1beta2"

Thus, I changed versions for ClusterRoleBinding and StatefulSet to v1 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767309/kubernetes-1-16-logstash-helm-chat-no-matches-for-kind-statefulset-in-version), then I got this error.

> persistentvolumeclaim/kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc created
> statefulset.apps/kubeflow-bootstrapper created Error from server
> (AlreadyExists): error when creating "bootstrapper.yaml":
> clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubeflow-cluster-admin"
> already exists

So, I also delete the clusterrolebindings `kubeflow-cluster-admin` and rerun `kubectl create -f bootstrapper.yaml`.
Then, I got expected result.

```
namespace/kubeflow-admin created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubeflow-cluster-admin created
persistentvolumeclaim/kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc created
statefulset.apps/kubeflow-bootstrapper created
```

I checked the existence of namespaces to be created by `kubectl get ns`, then

```
NAME                   STATUS   AGE
default                Active   8h
kube-node-lease        Active   8h
kube-public            Active   8h
kube-system            Active   8h
kubeflow-admin         Active   60s
kubernetes-dashboard   Active   8h
```

But, I got `No resources found in kubeflow namespace.` by `kubectl -n kubeflow get svc`

I already checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157855/kubeflow-setup-returns-no-resources-found). I waited long but I don't get any results.

I run `docker images` then there is no `gcr.io/kubeflow-images-public/bootstrapper:v0.2.0`. Thus it seems bootstrap failed.

Original `bootstrapper.yaml`

```
---
# Namespace for bootstrapper
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kubeflow-admin
---
# Make kubeflow-admin admin
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubeflow-cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: kubeflow-admin
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
# Store ksonnet apps
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc
  namespace: kubeflow-admin
  labels:
    app: kubeflow-ksonnet
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kubeflow-bootstrapper
  namespace: kubeflow-admin
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubeflow-bootstrapper
  serviceName: kubeflow-bootstrapper
  template:
    metadata:
      name: kubeflow-bootstrapper
      labels:
        app: kubeflow-bootstrapper
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubeflow-bootstrapper
        image: gcr.io/kubeflow-images-public/bootstrapper:v0.2.0
        workingDir: /opt/bootstrap
        command: [ "/opt/kubeflow/bootstrapper"]
        args: [
          "--in-cluster",
          "--namespace=kubeflow",
          "--apply",
          # change config here if you want to use customized config.
          # "--config=/opt/kubeflow/default.yaml"
          # app-dir: path to store your ks apps in pod's PersistentVolume
          "--app-dir=/opt/bootstrap/default"
          ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc
          mountPath: /opt/bootstrap
      volumes:
      - name: kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kubeflow-ksonnet-pvc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Summary**

- [This document](https://v0-2.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-minikube/) is deprecated. I realized the version of this site was `v0-2`.
- I followed [this Japanese document](https://qiita.com/ozora/items/961f647470869705bcb5).
  `hack/setup-kubeflow.sh` is an installation tool. This is not mentioned in the `kubeflow/manifests` repository. This was the breakthrough for me.
- I read [this document](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/tree/master) carefully. And I found the there was prerequisite for compatibility and tools I installed did not follow the requirements.
- Succeeded versions and branch I tried.

Ubuntu 20.0.4
minikube *v1.26.1*
kustomize *v3.2.0*
kubectl *v1.21.14*
kubeflow/manifests *v1.6-branch*